# WPF KeyTrigger not triggered when KeyBinding exists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, I have a `TextBox` that has a `KeyBinding` and `KeyTrigger` on it, but it seems that the `KeyTrigger` is not invoked.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding LogCommand}" CommandParameter="from KeyBinding"/>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:KeyTrigger Key="Return">
                ...
            </ei:KeyTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
</Window>
```

Is there any way to invoke both of them? I want to do this because there is something I don't want to do in ViewModel.

Comment: I don't really understand what namespace are you using for `Interaction.Triggers` but you should put down here the proper code related to that assembly. Otherwise, I tend to believe you just did a mistake specifying in an "unproper" way the `Trigger` configuration for your `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put both in the interaction.Triggers part and remove the direct input bindings:

```
<TextBox>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:KeyTrigger Key="Return">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LogCommand}" CommandParameter="from KeyBinding"/>
                ...
            </ei:KeyTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```